# Creating a Horizontal menu

Tags: menus, css

i'm new to creating wordpress themes and want a menu at the Top of my page.
I do have the following:
Header.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tutorial theme</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' =>'Top Navi', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap'  => '<ul id="menu-primary" class="menu" >%3$s</ul>'  ) ); ?>
<div id="header">
 </div>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
if (function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'main_nav' => 'Main Navigation Menu'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

And finally my css file http://pastebin.com/Pjr3THJm

However my menu comes out in a list, not horizontally.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is a **CSS**-specific question, not a **WordPress** question. (Side note: use `theme_location` rather than `menu` in your `wp_nav_menu()` call.)

Comment: @ChipBennett Sorry about that then, was not aware it was an css specific issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a CSS-only question.

You have to provide the `<li>` elements in your menu with the CSS style `display: inline;` (or 'inline-block').

Comment: I have no idea how to access the <li> elements as far as i can see i can only get to the <ul> element

Comment: Found it! had to add #menu-primary li {
display: inline;
} to my css file. Thanks!